# Seeking web service to return waterbody names for “unimpaired water segments”

Tags: data-request, geospatial, environment

I am looking for a ***dataset or a web service*** that can return a list of **unimpaired** water segments.

> There exists [ATTAINS](https://www.epa.gov/sites/production/files/2020-08/documents/attains_how_to_access_web_services_2020-08-31.pdf), a web service that will give the name of "**impaired** water segments" by using - a 12 digit HUC, and an Assessment Unit Id.

But I need a dataset for "**unimpaired** water segments".
Would anyone happen to know where to find one?

Comment: cross-posted at GIS: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/377583/112869

Comment: it is unclear for which location do you need the data, nor what does a water segment data include. These links should help you tho https://ca.water.usgs.gov/projects/reg_hydro/russian-river-streamflow.html and https://rivers.codefornature.org/#/map